# Set up messaging service similar to Tinder's

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, messaging, tinder

I'm creating an android app like Tinder and creating a messaging service similar to Tinder's- in that each user gets a push notification and messages with one another.

So far I'm using Google Cloud Messaging but running into some trouble with ID's & API synchronization.  Does anyone know what type of messaging/how code Tinder uses?

Answer (score 0):

May this tutorial can help u out:
http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/